# Disabling directory browsing with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Can some please clarify which of the following should be used for disabling directory browsing via htaccess?

Options -Indexes or Options All -Indexes

What is the difference between the two and in what instance should either be used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a .htaccess file with the following:

Options -Indexes

Answer (score 0):

Enabling directory browsing in Apache can be security issue - especially if used in production.

You can disable directory browsing by specifying `Options -Indexes`.

Note that it is better to do this in Apache configuration file / vhost files than in `.htaccess`.